# Typescript infer information from object in one of its keys

Tags: typescript, generics, types

Having

```
const a = {
  propOne: {
    methodOne(arg1, arg2: number) {
      console.info('hello...')
    }
  },
  proptwo: {
    b(fn, arg2) {
      fn('methodOne', 'hello') // Error
      fn('methodOne', 1) // OK
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to make this implementation work where I get the type Error and Intelisense when trying to use fn, in my b method. So basically fn first argument is one of the keys of propOne, and fn second argument is based on which method you selected. Since in the example I selected fn with 'methodOne' the second argument is then inferred to be number since methodOne's arg2 is of type number.

I was able to make this work if I write the types for propOne methods, but I wanted to know if there is a better way to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this to mostly work, except for what I think is a bug that we will get to later.

The first problem is we will need to use a function in order to help with out inference. Simple variables can have their type inferred from initialization expression or specified in a type annotation, for more complex behavior we need to use the inference behavior of functions.

We will use two type parameters, one for `propOne` and one for `propTwo` (which I have renamed as `actions` and `mutations` as we discussed on twitter, the original names were just stand-ins for Vue store props)

Once we have the type parameters captured, it is just a matter of transforming the type parameter for `actions` into a suitable parameter for the function

```
type Func = (...a: any[]) => void;
type SkipFirstParameter<T extends Func> = T extends (a: any, ... r: infer P) => any ? P : [];
type Actions<M extends Record<string, Func>> = <MK extends keyof M>(mutation: MK, ...a: SkipFirstParameter<M[MK]>) => void

function create<T, M extends Record<string, Func>, A extends Record<string, (f: Actions<M>, ...a: any[]) => void>>(o: {    
  mutations: M
  actions: A
}) {
  return o
}
const a = create({
  mutations: {
    methodOne: (arg1: number, arg2: number) => {
      console.info('hello...')
    },
  },
  actions: {
    b: (fn, arg2: number)  => {
      fn("methodOne", arg2)
      fn("methodOne", "arg2")
    }
  }
});
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMZQLxQBQDocEMBcUuCIA2gLoCUaAfFAG4D2AlgCYDcAUKJFAMoBrZmBjMATgGdgABVxjcAWwjAIYgDwAVKBAAeKhKwmxESOui279hzASIkANFBxYoYwswQAzVVGnVUdMQgUAD8vlCEFFw80ACCSMDMjAgSagCy2noQBkYAShBIjGKsalJiHgDmjvDINGZQ6QDSmVZGAhAgjJ5QaTQYCnDAuInJhGmNjs62gsKikjJyisqq6aTj5DT+dExsnJyeJiMIUEhiEMMQmo4ZltnW+YXFpcDlCFXGtY6xLXd5BUUlMqVRwYTyEeJHVK9SZ4QhBChbBgsVh1DCMQgAbyg2KgnGxAyGkLGeKICSSKXBnAAvtQMSSzsA4GJjoxqZxCilgEQ0CczhcMHT8YNhuSJJiSfjlAALRisADyCAghAwcgqAEZCAg4AoAEaqRyqgBMmu1erEiMFOOxHIkjAANhAsB5PIwMAByKUQO12xjON2UCVQKn2EnBkm4MnJMVQS3YnXKzwIA1iCrGqBa3Wqai0GOB7GJjAAIiUwBl8sVheTqYDVvzCCLJbLCoglaghaNhZrOKpoeplHYQA)

You will notice I switched to arrow functions, instead of shorthand syntax or `function` expression. This is because inference behaves differently between arrow functions and the others. I believe this to be a compiler bug and field one [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38623) but if we use method of function syntax `M` will be inferred as `unknown`. This probably has something to do with the way TS tries to infer `this` for such functions, but the difference in behavior is probably a bug.

Comment: Hi Titian, I updated the example to be more specific to the real problem. If you want I can accept the original response, than ask a different question with that current problem. Let me know